# How to make a query from 4 tables

Tags: sql, inner-join, aggregation

I am having a problem creating a View using SQL. I need to make a View of 4 tables:

`tbl_school`, `tbl_teacher`, `tb_student`, and `tbl_class`.

This is my table structure:
[image: Table Structure]

And this is my View Statement

```
SELECT
tbl_school.school_id,
tbl_school.school_nm,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_class) AS class,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_teacher) AS teacher,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_student) AS student
FROM
tbl_school
INNER JOIN tbl_teacher ON tbl_school.school_id = tbl_teacher.school_id
INNER JOIN tbl_class ON tbl_teacher.teacher_id = tbl_class.teacher_id AND tbl_school.school_id = tbl_class.school_id
INNER JOIN tbl_student ON tbl_class.class_id = tbl_student.class_id
GROUP BY
tbl_school.school_id
```

And this is the query result:

[image: Query Result]

The problem is that I have one teacher in SD1 School and another teacher in SD2 School. Each teacher has one class and SD1 School has two students and SD2 School has one student.

Is there a way I can get the results that I desire?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aggregation containing `DISTINCT` keywords, and had better using aliasing and one more column (`tbl_school.school_nm`) within the `GROUP BY` list to make it a more proper SQL( *Btw some DBMS don't allow excluding that column from `GROUP BY` while `MySQL` allows* ) :

```
SELECT s.school_id, s.school_nm,
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.class_id) AS class,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.teacher_id) AS teacher,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.student_id) AS student -- this is a presumedly existing column within the student table
  FROM tbl_school s
  JOIN tbl_teacher t ON s.school_id = t.school_id
  JOIN tbl_class c ON t.teacher_id = c.teacher_id AND s.school_id = c.school_id
  JOIN tbl_student d ON c.class_id = d.class_id
 GROUP BY s.school_id, s.school_nm
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

It has been a while since I have done this, but have you tried adding a WHERE modifier to your internal SQL select statements? Like this...

Side note: It makes more sense, to me, to also have a FK on tbl_student that links them to which school that they're in.

```
SELECT
tbl_school.school_id,
tbl_school.school_nm,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_class WHERE school_id=tbl_school.school_id) AS class,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_teacher WHERE school_id=tbl_school.school_id) AS teacher,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_student) AS student
FROM
tbl_school
INNER JOIN tbl_teacher ON tbl_school.school_id = tbl_teacher.school_id
INNER JOIN tbl_class ON tbl_teacher.teacher_id = tbl_class.teacher_id AND tbl_school.school_id = tbl_class.school_id
INNER JOIN tbl_student ON tbl_class.class_id = tbl_student.class_id
GROUP BY
tbl_school.school_id
```